# I want to notify a group of emails from a google spreadsheet by google forms. It is possible?

Tags: google-forms

What is the best way to do this?

I know that its possible notify the form creator or specific email when some user submit the form, but how i can  notify a list of emails(users) from google spreadsheet without submit the form. it is possible?

How i can do this?

Basically the notify message would be something like this:

"Hello guys, please answer this questions.. etc.."

questions :  https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/example/viewform"

thank you advance

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the email adresses you have, paste them as recipient of your email (preferably as BCC) in your favorite mail client, and just send them the email with the content you wrote in your above question.